# BTC synchronization in Bitcore

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I had kept some BTC for for `synchronization` in `BITCORE` but now I need money, so want to SELL my BTC but the process of synchronization is still going on.....
In that case **can I stop the process of synchronization** in between and get all my **BTC back safely into my wallet?** So that I can then sell these BTC

If your answer is yes... you can stop the process and get my BTC safely then `HOW CAN I DO THAT?`

Comment: You have tagged this "bitcoin core" but your question is about "bitcore" which is different. Did you mean https://bitcore.cc which is a different currency (BTX), or https://bitcore.io which is a different wallet? also I am unsure why you associate storing money in a wallet with synchronisation - please explain.

Comment: No, I meant Bitcoin Core https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/    I referred to this as I wanted to do transactions of Bitcoins but as they are in synchronisation I can't.....

Comment: the BTC is still in your wallet, synchronisation just means the program is downloading the blockchain to find out what happened to your BTC, it doesn't know that the BTC is in your wallet until it does that

Comment: Yes I know that but the problem is I can't transact that BTC as the synchronisation is going on ...... right? as the transaction would not be confirmed.... please give me a solution so that I can sell my BTC as of now as I need money as this process is not allowing me to do so